# How can I get a complete circle with labels around the circle

Tags: circles, luamplib

I got this semi-circle for illustration and I need the two mouths to touch each other like exactly a circle still with metric label like what I have in the **MWE**

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,graphicx,autobreak}
\usepackage{changepage,mathtools,amsthm,tikz,blindtext}
\usepackage{inputenc,float,caption,subcaption,enumitem}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,font=normalfont,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,font=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes} %for single quoatation mark
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%for arc and angles
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
    \begin{mplibcode}
        beginfig(1);
        path C, C'; 
        C = subpath(2,0) of fullcircle rotated 45 scaled 640;
        C' = C scaled 1.02;
        numeric p[];
        p1    = 1/8;
        p2    = 2/8;
        p3    = 3/8;
        p.t   = 5/8;
        p.tt  = 6/8;
        p.ttt = 7/8;
        p.n   = 9/8;
        p.l  = 10/8;
        p.zz = 13/8;
        for t=  1/64 step 1/64 until   3/64: drawdot point t of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
        for t= 29/64 step 1/64 until  35/64: drawdot point t of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
        for t= 61/64 step 1/64 until  67/64: drawdot point t of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
        for t= 89/64 step 1/64 until  95/64: drawdot point t of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
        for t=116/64 step 1/64 until 119/64: drawdot point t of C' withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
    
        forsuffixes $=1,2,3,t,tt,ttt,n,l,zz:
        draw point p$ of C -- point p$ of C' withcolor 2/3 blue;
        label.top("$x_{" & 
            if     str $ = "tt" : "t+1" 
            elseif str $ = "ttt": "t+2" 
            elseif str $ = "zz" : "n+l-1" 
            else: str $ fi
            & "}$", point 1 of C') rotated (45-45*p$);
        endfor
    
            draw C;
    
        vardef mark(suffix a, b)(expr s, T) =
        save arc; path arc;
        arc = subpath(p.a, p.b) of C scaled s;
        interim ahangle  := 180; interim ahlength := 5;
        drawdblarrow arc withcolor 2/3 green;
    
        save pp; picture pp; 
        pp = thelabel(T rotated angle direction 1/2 of arc, point 1/2 of arc);
        unfill bbox pp; draw pp;
        enddef;
    
        mark(1, t, 0.95, textext("$B_1$"));
        mark(2, tt, 0.90, textext("$B_2$"));
        mark(3, ttt, 0.85, textext("$B_3$"));
        mark(n, zz, 0.95, textext("$B_k$"));
    
        endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
    \caption{Circular Block Bootstrap}
    \label{fig5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```